# Magento: Revert price data from index. False price data saved, but not indexed

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

i hope i am able to describe the problem correctly here, as it is quite complex. I guess you guys are my last chance.

We have ca. 120 config products based on 600 simple products. Some days ago, we accidently overwrote all the prices of the simple products with false prices. We did not notice as in the frontend every price is still ok, they are not indexed.

So we now have the correct prices in the frontend, but the wrong prices for the simple products in the backend.

Is there any method the get the prices from the indexed frontend and write them back in the backend?

Until i reindex all proces should be ok in the frontend.

Does anyone have any idea what i could do to get the prices right again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you browse the database, there should be a catalog_product_flat_1 table - this is basically your product index. You should have columns for all the product attributes (including SKU and Price) so you could export this table, then do a product export from Magento, then update all the prices/SKUs accordingly and re-import. Or duplicate the flat_1 table, then write a PHP script to loop through it, updating all the prices, then re-index your data (after checking it's worked of course!)